# Where clause in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Suppose I've a dataset, it has deparment column (sales, marketing...) and many many other columns. I want to create a pie chart which includes info only on sales department. How can i do this? I don't want to change query because I'll do the same thing for marketing departmnet and etc. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a filter on the data set, by going to dataset properties > filters 
Add your Department column to the filer and set the text equal to the department you want. Repeat for each department.

Comment: But I don't want to create many datasets, i want to create 1 dataset

Comment: Ok, thanks, i guess i can filter in pie chart itself

Comment: Yes, either in the data set or in the data source for the pie chart